# How to transfer data from one page to another xamarin

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, data-transfer

I have three pages, I enter the data on the second page and transfer it to page number one, returning to it at the same time, there is no problem with this, I use navigation, like this:

```
private async void OnSaveTitleButtonCliked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var title_data = new LabelViewModel
        {
            Label = editor.Text,
            Date = DateTime.Now
        };
        var mainpage = new MainPage();
        mainpage.BindingContext = title_data;
        await Navigation.PushAsync(mainpage);

    }
```

But I also need to transfer this data to page number three, so that I can go there from the first page and see, I tried the mvvm, but so far I have not understood how it works.
Please tell me how to do it better:)

Comment: a page is just a c# class.  You can pass data to it via it's constructor or a public property or method.  If you need data to be accessible from many pages, you can add it to your Application object, or use a static class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pass data by constructor:**

In Page1:

```
private async void GoToPage2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var title_data = new LabelViewModel
    {
        Label = editor.Text,
        Date = DateTime.Now
    };

    //Pass the model here
    var Page2 = new Page2(title_data);           
    await Navigation.PushAsync(Page2);

}
```

In Page2:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{

    public LabelViewModel model;

    public Page2(LabelViewModel m) {

        InitializeComponent();

        this.model = m;
        //You can use your model here

    }
}
```

**Pass data by public property:**

In Page1:

```
private async void GoToPage2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var title_data = new LabelViewModel
    {
        Label = editor.Text,
        Date = DateTime.Now
    };
    var Page2 = new Page2();
    //Pass the model here
    Page2.model = title_data;
    await Navigation.PushAsync(Page2);

}
```

In Page2:

```
public partial class Page2 : ContentPage
{

    public LabelViewModel model;
    public Page2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //You can use your model here
        Console.WriteLine(model.Label);
        Console.WriteLine(model.Date);
    }
}
```

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you very much, it helped, but another problem appeared, I need to dynamically add objects to the page, I store them in ObservableCollection <LabelViewModel>, the problem is that only one object is saved to the collection - the last one, I add the object on the second page and I need see a list of all added objects on the third page.

Answer (score 0):

I'll let some examples here

On the first page (who calls the second one)

```
  private async void MenuLista(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var item = (ModelosPPP)((Button)sender).BindingContext;
            if (PopupRunnning != false)
                return;

            var page = new MenuListSV(item);
            PopupRunnning = true;

            page.Action += async (a, b) =>
            {
                switch (b)
                {
                    case 1:
                        await DisplayAlert("PDF", null, "ok");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        await DisplayAlert("Reenviar", null, "ok");
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        await DisplayAlert("Excluir", null, "ok");
                        break;
                }

            };

            page.Disappearing += (c, d) =>
            {
                PopupRunnning = false;

            };

            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(page);

        }
```

in Second Page

```
public partial class MenuListSV : PopupPage
    {
        public MenuListSV(Models.ModelosPPP obj)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BindingContext = obj;
        }


        public EventHandler<int> Action;

        public async void MenuChoice(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var btn = sender as Button;
            switch (btn.Text)
            {
                case "Abrir PDF":
                    Action?.Invoke(this, 1);
                    break;
                case "Reenviar":
                    Action?.Invoke(this, 2);
                    break;
                case "Excluir":
                    Action?.Invoke(this, 3);
                    break;

            }
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PopAsync();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try:)

Comment: ofc this work, i use that all the time, i'll update the answer my code

Comment: Updated, let me know if u want some more help